# Holding down a button for repeated action -- is there an android:onClick for holds? (in XML files)

Tags: java, android, xml, button

Hopefully the question says it all... I've been searching the web for an easy solution, I'm surprised to see there isn't? I expected this to be a basic functionality that I could just add into the XML file? Alternatives are welcome, but I already know they're out there. I just want to know if this simple method is possible (couldn't seem to find anything in the documentation but who knows)

Comment: Why not set a variable for something like `isHolding` to equal `true` when `onClick` and `false` for `onMouseUp`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't any default way of doing this. But it's fairly easy accomplishing this using the onTouch() Event. The following code will repeat a task every 0.5 sec starting the time you touch a button. The tasks will be cancelled whenever you release the button.

```
Handler repeatedHandler = new Handler();
Runnable newRunnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override 
    public void run() {
      //Code for the task that needs to be repeated
      //...
      //...
      repeatedHandler.postDelayed(newRunnable, 500);
    }
  };

button.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        switch(event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            repeatedHandler.postDelayed(newRunnable, 500);
            break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            repeatedHandler.removeCallbacks(newRunnable);
            break;
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

you can set OnLongClickListener like

```
btn.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {

@Override
public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
---code here---
return false;
}
});
```

or you can set onTouchListner on button

```
btn.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

switch(event.getAction())
{
case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
---code here---
break;
case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
---code here---
break;
}
});
```

I don't know how to set onLongClickListner from xml

Answer (score 0):

You can use `OnLongClickListener()` for `Button`

Follow this link to read more about it...

[View.OnLongClickListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnLongClickListener.html)

**Example :**

[Examples for android.view.View.OnLongClickListener](http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=android.view.View.OnLongClickListener)